# How do I loop through each string in my list?

Tags: python, list, function, loops, append

I tried this piece of code, but it only performs the function on the first string in the list:

## returns the first and last 2 characters of the given list of strings

```
def both_ends(list):
    finalList = []
    for s in list:
        if s > 2:
            return s[0] + s[1] + s[-2] + s[-1]
        else:
            return s

    finalList.append(s)
    return finalList

list = ('apple', 'pizza', 'x', 'joke')
print both_ends(string)
```

How would I make this function run through all of the strings in the list?

Comment: That's what `map` function is for!

Comment: `print both_ends(string)`? Do you mean `print both_ends(list)`?

Comment: And of course the so called `list`is not a list but a `tuple`. So this code manages to overwrite the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function while at the same time bedazzling the user by a misleading variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is because you are returning the result directly , so it returns after you go through the first string itself. Instead you should put the result in the `finalList` you create and return the result at the end.

And some other things -

1. As said in the other answer, you want to check the length of the string.
2. The length of the string should be greater than 4 , otherwise, you would end up adding some characters multiple times.
3. Do not use names like `list` for variables, it ends up shadowing the builtin functions and so you would not be able to use `list()` to create list after that.
4. Last issue is you should call you function with your list, not `string` .

Example -

```
def both_ends(list):
    finalList = []
    for s in list:
        if len(s) > 4:
            finalList.append(s[:2] + s[-2:])
        else:
            finalList.append(s)
    return finalList
```

---

An easier way to do this -

```
def both_ends(s):
    return s[:2] + s[-2:] if len(s) > 4 else s

lst = ('apple', 'pizza', 'x', 'joke')
print map(both_ends, lst)          #You would need `list(map(...))` for Python 3.x
```

Demo -

```
>>> def both_ends(s):
...     return s[:2] + s[-2:] if len(s) > 4 else s
... 
>>> lst = ('apple', 'pizza', 'x', 'joke')
>>> print map(both_ends, lst) 
['aple', 'piza', 'x', 'joke']
```

Or even list comprehension , though to me that makes it a bit less readable -

```
[s[:2] + s[-2:] if len(s) > 4 else s for s in lst]
```

Demo -

```
>>> lst = ('apple', 'pizza', 'x', 'joke')
>>> [s[:2] + s[-2:] if len(s) > 4 else s for s in lst]
['aple', 'piza', 'x', 'joke']
```

Comment: Oh no, my and your's answer is almost identical. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the length of the string, not the string itself. Hence, doing `s > 2` doesn't do what you want it to do:

```
def both_ends(lst):
    finalList = []
    for s in lst:
        if len(s) > 2:
            finalList.append(s[0] + s[1] + s[-2] + s[-1])
        else:
            finalList.append(s)
    return finalList

lst = ['apple', 'pizza', 'x', 'joke']
print both_ends(lst)
```

Few other things:

- Don't name variables `list`. It will override the built-in type.
- You have a tuple `(..., ...)`. A list is with square brackets.
- You have `print both_ends(string)`, and not putting in your list.

And finally, you can probably shorten up your code:

```
print [s[:2] + s[-2:] if len(s) > 2 else s for s in lst]
```

Comment: Your implementation will print `'aple'` and not exercise any of the other strings in `lst`.

Comment: @BillLynch It prints each string for me

Comment: @BillLynch Oo sorry I was looking at the list comprehension not the actual function. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues that caught my eye.

- You are returning immediately after the first iteration, so getting only the first element.
- I think you want to compare if the length is greater than 4, so do `len(s)>4`
- Don't use a datatype name as a variable name. Use used `list`, don't use that.

Don't return immediately, rather append to the list.

```
 def both_ends(lst):
    finalList = []
    for s in lst:
        if len(s) > 4:
           finalList.append( s[0] + s[1] + s[-2] + s[-1])
        else:
           finalList.append(s)


    return finalList

lst = ['apple', 'pizza', 'x', 'joke']
print both_ends(lst)
```

Output:

```
['aple', 'piza', 'x', 'joke']
```